# Computing differentiation rule with error bound

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

I have values for $x$, $f(x)$ and fixed error bounds for $f^{(n)}(x)=c_n$ for $n=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. I want to compute $f^\prime(x)$ using $f(x-h),f(x)$, and $f(x+h)$. Since the function is continuous in $C^5$, by Richardson expansion we have,

$$f(x-h)=f(x) - hf^{1}(x) + \frac{h^2}{2!}f^{(2)}(x) - \frac{h^3}{3!}f^{(3)}(x) + \frac{h^4}{4!}f^{(4)}(x) - \frac{h^5}{5!}f^{(5)}(\xi^-)$$

$$f(x+h)=f(x) + hf^{1}(x) + \frac{h^2}{2!}f^{(2)}(x) + \frac{h^3}{3!}f^{(3)}(x) + \frac{h^4}{4!}f^{(4)}(x) + \frac{h^5}{5!}f^{(5)}(\xi^+)$$

for $\xi^- \in [x-h,x], \xi^+ \in [x,x+h]$. Taking the difference $f(x+h)-f(x-h)$ gives us the following result for $f^{(1)}(x)$,

$$f^{(1)}(x) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} - \frac{h^2}{3!}f^{(3)}(x)-\frac{h^4}{5!}f^{(5)}(\xi)$$

---

I'm comfortable up to this point, however, I'm unsure whether I'm supposed to do anything about the two remaining terms when numerically solving for $f'(x)$.

For example, suppose I choose $h=1$ and have $f(x)=\{-1,0,1\}$ for $x=\{-1,0,1$}. Then is $f^\prime(0) = 1$?

Or should I be including the $f^{(3)(x)}$ and $f^{5}(\xi)$ terms as well? How would I get the value of $f^{(3)}$ in that case? I would imagine having to deal with errors recursively.

Also, is the error of this differentiation rule the bound for $f^{(3)}(x)$ or $f^{(5)}(x)$? Choosing $c_3$ makes sense as it is larger, however I'm not aware of any particular rule regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you want the approximation of the derivative to be close to the actual derivative value, i.e., the terms constituting the deviation from there to be rather small. So you might think about choosing $h=10^{-8}$ so that the error incurred by the third derivative term has relatively the same size as the numerical uncertainty $\mu=2^{-52}\simeq 10^{-15}$ of IEEE `double` numbers.

Actually, there is an error of magnitude $f(x)\mu$ associated with the evaluation of $f(x\pm h)$ so that the numerical error is qualitatively of the form
$$
\frac{|f(x)|\mu}{h}+\frac{|f^{(3)}(x)|}{6}h^2
$$
which is minimal for $h$ of the magnitude $\sqrt[3]\mu=10^{-5}$.

The following graphic demonstrates this strikingly, the one-sided difference quotient with discretization error $O(h)$ is best around $h=\sqrt\mu=10^{-8}$, the central one as derived close to $h=10^{-5}$ and the extrapolated central difference quotient with discretization error $O(h^4)$ is best around the magnitude $h=\sqrt[5]\mu=10^{-3}$

[image]

Comment: Interesting, although in my case the minimum distance between sample points is 1, so I cannot experiment with minimizing $h$. The bounds of each of the derivatives provided are $f^{(x)}(x)=10^{-n}$ for $n=1,\ldots,5$. Given this, did I get the numerical computation of $f^\prime(x)$ mentioned in my post right, or do I need to account for the error the other derivatives?

Comment: This decay of the derivatives is not overwhelming, but sufficient to disregard all error terms but the first, which is about $10^{-3}/6$. Thus you should not expect better than 3 digits accuracy in you results. Use extrapolation, which then involves $x\pm 2h$ to get the first error term to be the 5th derivative with a correspondingly smaller error estimate.