# Truncation and rounding error bound derivation for finite difference approximation to the first derivative

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error, truncation-error

Finite difference  approximation to the first derivative:
$$
f'(x)= \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}
$$

Heath's book on Scientific computing Section 1.2.4, Example 1.3 says truncation error for the finite difference approximation is bounded by $\frac{|f''(t)|h}{2}$ for $t$ near $x$, and the rounding error in computing the finite difference is bounded by $\frac{2\epsilon}{h} $

How are these bounds calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- By the linear Taylor expansion with quadratic remainder term, and
- by assuming that the evaluation of $f$ has a seemingly random error bounded in size by $ϵ$.

See [Computing differentiation rule with error bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214051/computing-differentiation-rule-with-error-bound) for a plot of the error against the exact derivative value in different approximation schemes for the first derivative.

Comment: Why is rounding error bounded by 2e/h? Would'nt it be e/h?

Comment: Because you have two evaluations of $f$, both errors could go in opposite directions, adding in the difference.